# Implicit substitution

Tags: scala, implicit

I have some types:

```
trait OutputHandler[A]

case class TypeA()

case class TypeB()
```

A method that takes an implicit parameter:

```
def process[A](a: Any => A)(implicit handler: OutputHandler[A]) {}
```

A value defined as:

```
implicit val handler = new OutputHandler[TypeA] {}
```

How can I create a generic implicit value of `List[T]` where `T` can be any type that has an implicit value defined? That is, can I call `process(List(TypeA()))` or `process(List(TypeB())` whenever I have `implicit val a: OutputHandler[TypeA]`, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with an `implicit def` that returns the `OutputHandler[List[A]]`:

```
implicit val handler = new OutputHandler[TypeA] {}

implicit def listOf[A](implicit ev: OutputHandler[A]): OutputHandler[List[A]] = new OutputHandler[List[A]] {
  // can implement this output handler using ev: OutputHandler[A]
}

process(t => List(TypeA())) // compiles, because OutputHandler[TypeA] exists
process(t => List(TypeB())) // does not compile, as expected, because there's no OutputHandler[TypeB]
```